# Writing variables from right-angle triangle WRT one another

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I require clarification on the following question and how to properly implement a few of these exercises:

[image]

For example, when the author mentions $y$ in terms of $z$, $\theta$, would how would I represent this?

I had imagined something like:
$$y = \sin(\theta) = \frac{z}{x}?$$

However, this involves $x$ and the question does not mention $x$ for exercise 1.

Comment: $\tan(\theta )=\frac{z}{y}$

Comment: @callculus42 So exercise 2 would then by $\cos(\phi) = \frac{y}{z}$?

Comment: @callculus42 The solutions suggest its $z \cos(\theta)$ for exercise 1

Comment: Mhhh, at exercise 2 it is $\theta$, not $\phi$

Comment: @callculus42 whats the best way to think about this would you say? Because, I thought it was: "IF S then D/N" where D means denominator, and N means numerator. So we get $S = \frac{N}{D}$, however, when testing on (7) this is correct, but on (1) this is incorrect. For example, $y = \frac{\theta}{z}$ which is wrong, but for (7), $\phi = \frac{y}{x}$ will lead to a correct solution.

Comment: I believe I have cracked it! thank you